# How to force Magento to load a module?

Tags: third-party-module

Let's say that I have a module that resides in `community/Company/Badmodulename`, this is an old version of the module and the current version of it resides in `community/Company/Actualmodule`.

Now, I have a server with the old version of the module, I remove all the old files and install the new version. I also update `core_config_data` so that all the references there that used to point to `company_badmodulename/...` now use the new path the module uses (e.g. `company_actualmodule/...`). If the module has an install script that results in a line in `core_resource` then obviously I'll also update this if applicable.

Now I try clearing my Magento cache, I re-save user roles and I restart Apache. Yet the new version of the module isn't loading.

Oh well, maybe my new version of the module is broken? But it's not, it works fine on dozens of other Magento installs, it's just that this particular Magento install apparently just doesn't want to put in the effort to try to actually load this module.

This is something which happens to me way too often and I'd like to know, what's the one surefire way to give Magento a good-ol' "no, you go through everything in `app/etc/modules/` and you load it, right now!" kick in the pants?

And in case you're wondering, yes I'm having this problem right now. The config panel for the old version of the module is no longer there but looking in the "disable modules output" list I still see the old version of the module which has been completely removed and the new one is nowhere to be found (and the new one isn't broken, it works fine on other Magento installs, file permissions are fine, the problem is that Magento isn't even trying to load it, that's what I want to force).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a surefire way, cause a lot of things are involved here. First thing to do is to regain control over your cache. You obviously don't have control over it, because a file that doesn't exist can only be referenced from the cache. In this case, the module file in `app/etc/modules`.

Two things to do here:

1. Disable any opcode cache
2. Use the cache store native method to flush it, so `rm -rf var/cache` or `redis-cli -n # flushdb`

Then verify the module list.

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to be the issue. I relied on admin panel's cache flushing to actually flush the cache, turns out this didn't actually completely flush the cache. I guess I should've figured this out on my own faster seeing as how I've had similar issues in the past when Magento has placed garbage data in ``var/cache`` that it refuses to remove…

Answer (score 0):

Magento load the modules declarations in `Mage_Core_Model_Config::init($options=array())`

```
public function init($options=array())
{
    $this->setCacheChecksum(null);
    $this->_cacheLoadedSections = array();
    $this->setOptions($options);
    $this->loadBase();

    $cacheLoad = $this->loadModulesCache();
    if ($cacheLoad) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->loadModules();
    $this->loadDb();
    $this->saveCache();
    return $this;
}
```

if the loadModulesCache return `true` Magento does not load the files, if `false` it loads the modules declaration with `$this->loadModules();`

So apparently, if you correctly clear the cache, Magento reloads all the `app/etc/modules/` files.

You can debug the `Mage_Core_Model_Config::loadCache()` method to see why Magento cache success to load from the cache.

Are you sure you have cleared the good cache system ? Are you using Memcache or Redis (or other) ?